# Reading txt file with php

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm trying to pars ip in line which located 2 lines upper from specific words that I know, can somebody give an idea how to do it?
This is part of my code...

```
if (($handle = fopen('FW1-20160802_1530.conf', "r")) !== FALSE){
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000,";")) !== FALSE) 
..
else if (preg_match('/(.*site-5552)/',$data[0],$match))
            {
                list(,$line)=$match;
                $REV_ARRAY[$site_name]['line']=$line;           
            }
```

That gives me the third line of the following output:

```
edit 2
        set dst 10.23.255.252 255.255.255.252
        set device "abc"
        set comment "Static Route site-5552"
```

But as I mentioned above I need to catch the ip: "10.23.255.252" which exists two lines upper.

The text file is too big so I pasted just part of it.
According to site number (in this example- 5552) I need to find the relevant ip (10.93.255.252)

```
edit "Site-5552"
    set asdaa
    set asdsdaa
    set aadsda
    set aasdda
    set aaaa
    set adsaa
    set aadsa
    set vvxv
    set dsds
    set czx
```

ssasd

```
edit 2
        set dst 10.93.255.252 255.255.255.252
        set device "sdasdsad"
        set comment "Static Route for LTE site-5552"
```

Comment: We can't tell without seeing more of your code. That being said, I'm gonna guess that there is a better overall approach to what you're doing.

Either way, show us a bit more of this routine

Answer (score 1):

K.D you need the `s` modifier to tell the regex engine to include new-line characters when matching against `.`

Change your regex pattern from:

```
/(.*site-5552)/
```

To:

```
/set dst ([\d\.]+).*site-5552/s
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/Wrf6Q)

Comment: @K.D Without more info, I can't tell you why it doesn't work. The demo I linked to shows that it should work with the source text you supplied and the regex pattern that I used

Comment: I've added more info and I'm using preg_match for that. I'm getting an error when I'm trying to use $match [];